# Factorial push to array

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm making a factorial. How do I push specific number to an array? For example if we factor a 14 then the result will be 1, 2, 7, 14 then I only want to push 2 and 7 to the array. Another example is if we factor 18, then the values that I want to push is only 2, 3, 6, 9. I want to exclude the 1 * 14 or 1 * 18. How can I do that?

```
const isNFactored = function(value, number) {
    let i;
    let array = [];
    for(i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
        if(value % i === 0) {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
    
    console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: You can simply fix your algorithm by changing the lower and upper limit of the loop :
for(i = 2; i < value; i++) {
and you seem to have an unused argument, which is number

Comment: Also, don't forget to *return* `array`.